# How to synchronize tasks between two forms?

Tags: c#, progress-bar

I have one application in which after performing task1, I have to show a progress bar on screen. Immediately after showing the progress bar, I have to start performing task2. When task2 is finished, the progress bar will be hidden from screen.

Task1 and task2 are performed in separate Forms.

I do not want to use a worker thread for this. And also, on progress bar, there should not be any user input for hiding it.

I am a beginner in C#. Please help for achieving this.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You really *do* want to use a worker thread for this, preferably handled by the [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) class as it takes care of many details and provides easy Winform events/interoperability; including the ability to report progress.

Comment: Why do you think you dont want to use a worker thread?

Comment: Hi, If I use a background worker (BackgroundWorker class) thread then will it communicate between two different forms?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but odd.
You have to add calls to refresh progress form in the task2.

```
   public partial class ProgressForm : Form
    {
        public ProgressForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.TopMost = true;
        }

        public void SetProgress(int progress)
        {
            this.progressBar1.Value = progress;
            // Allow the form to be repainted
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
    } 


    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        ProgressForm progressForm = new ProgressForm();
        void Task2()
        {
            ShowProgress(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                ShowProgress(i * 10);
            }
            HideProgress();
        }


        void ShowProgress(int progress)
        {
            if (!progressForm.Visible)
                progressForm.Show();
            progressForm.SetProgress(progress);
        }

        void HideProgress()
        {
            progressForm.Hide();  // or Close, it depends from app logic
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Task2();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If "two forms" you mentioned above are within an application(not separate), there is another way that you can update your progress bar by using new asynchronous programming model in C# 5 and .NET framework 4.5. This tutorial might help you:

[Async, Await, Tasks, and UI synchronization with C# 5, .NET 4.5 and WinForms](http://www.danderson.me/posts/async-and-await-ui-synchronization-with-c-5-net-4-5-and-winforms/)

I'm also recommend you read about Task Parallel Library in .NET 4.0